# translating bash script to python

Tags: python, bash, scripting, subprocess

I have some simple bash scripts that I would like to translate in python. I need to define some bash environment variables before calling the external program with subprocess. In particular I need to load a module environment. The original bash looks something like this

```
#!/bin/bash 
source /etc/profile.d/modules.sh
module purge
module load intel

./my_code
```

### I want to call `my_code` with subprocess, but how do I pass the variables defined by `module` to the shell?

Edit:

my first attempt to convert the above script is

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt
import subprocess

subprocess.call("source /etc/profile.d/modules.sh",shell=True)
subprocess.call("module purge",shell=True)
subprocess.call("module load intel",shell=True)
subprocess.call("./mycode",shell=True)
```

but this fails, because the environment variables (that I think are LIBRARY_PATH and PATH and C_INCLUDE) are modified in the shell launched by subprocess, but then this shell dies and these variables are not inherited by subsequent shells. So the question is: how can I launch a modules command and then save the relevant variables with os.environ ?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I think now the question is clear, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a multiline string so that the environment is modified in the same shell process:

```
from subprocess import check_call

check_call("""
source /etc/profile.d/modules.sh
module purge
module load intel

./my_code
""", shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")
```

See also [Calling the “source” command from subprocess.Popen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22086176/4279)

Comment: yeah, this is certainly a solution. but you know the above code is a simplification, between module load and the call to mycode I do some string manipulation and I actually call several programs that use the same modules, so this would not be very elegant

Comment: @simona: what do you mean: *"would not be very elegant"*?

Comment: it seemed cleaner to me to pass the environment variables from one shell to the other, like you would do in bash with export, there must be a way to do that.

Comment: @simona: Why do you need several shell processes? Also, check out [the link that I've added above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22086176/4279)

Answer (score 0):

`import os`

`os.environ` is a dict of environment variables (exported shell variables)

Comment: I modified my question