# How to source script via python

Tags: python, bash

I can source bash script (without shebang) easy as bash command in terminal but trying to do the same via python command

```
sourcevars = "cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa && . ./vars"
runSourcevars = subprocess.Popen(sourcevars, shell = True)
```

or

```
sourcevars = [". /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/vars"]
runSourcevars = subprocess.Popen(sourcevars, shell = True)
```

I receive :

> Please source the vars script first (i.e. "source ./vars")
>   Make sure you have edited it to reflect your configuration.

What's the matter, how to do it correctly?I've read some topics here,e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7040592/407651) but could not solve my problem using given advices. Please explain with examples.

UPDATED:

```
# os.chdir = ('/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa')
initvars = "cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa && . ./vars && ./easy-rsa ..."


# initvars = "cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa && . ./vars"
# initvars = [". /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/vars"]
cleanall = ["/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/clean-all"]
# buildca  = ["printf '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n' | /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/build-ca"]
# buildkey = ["printf '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nyes\n ' | /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/build-key AAAAAA"]
# buildca  = "cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa && printf '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n' | ./build-ca"
runInitvars = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True)
# runInitvars = subprocess.Popen(initvars,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True, executable="/bin/bash")
runCleanall = subprocess.Popen(cleanall , shell=True)

# runBuildca = subprocess.Popen(buildca , shell=True)
# runBuildca.communicate()
# runBuildKey = subprocess.Popen(buildkey, shell=True )
```

UPDATE 2

```
buildca  = ["printf '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n' | /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/build-ca"]
runcommands = subprocess.Popen(initvars+cleanall+buildca, shell = True)
```

Comment: You get that error from those snippets or from some *other* call after that? Because those should work fine but will only be in effect for that **one** shell instance and will not affect later shell instances or the running python script/environment.

Comment: Generally I need to run set of commands where shown is the first one and get this error from very beginning

Comment: You need to run all the commands in just one `subprocess.Popen` instance, since they're scoped to a single shell.

Comment: BTW, spaces should be used around `=`s in assignments, but not argument lists. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations

Comment: Your example shown (and thank you for editing it in) *doesn't* do as I recommended, contrary claim notwithstanding: It's still running your `cleanall` command in a separate shell from where you ran `initvars`.

Comment: `runCleanall = subprocess.Popen(' && '.join([initvars] + cleanall))` would be a little closer.

Comment: That said, why are you doing this in the first place? I mean, the impedence mismatch between Python and shell is making your life much harder and buying you no advantage over either using easy-rsa directly from shell or using a native Python CA library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with this in and of itself:

```
# What you're already doing -- this is actually fine!
sourcevars = "cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa && . ./vars"
runSourcevars = subprocess.Popen(sourcevars, shell=True)

# ...*however*, it won't have any effect at all on this:
runOther = subprocess.Popen('./easy-rsa build-key yadda yadda', shell=True)
```

However, if you **subsequently** try to run a second `subprocess.Popen(..., shell=True)` command, you'll see that it doesn't have any of the variables set by sourcing that configuration.

**This is entirely normal and expected behavior**: The entire point of using `source` is to modify the state of the active shell; each time you create a new `Popen` object with `shell=True`, it's starting a new shell -- their state isn't carried over.

Thus, combine into a single call:

```
prefix = "cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa && . ./vars && "
cmd = "/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/clean-all"
runCmd = subprocess.Popen(prefix + cmd, shell=True)
```

...such that you're using the results of sourcing the script in the same shell invocation as that in which you actually source the script.

---

Alternately (and this is what I'd do), require your Python script to be invoked by a shell which already has the necessary variables in its environment. Thus:

```
# ask your users to do this
set -a; . ./vars; ./yourPythonScript
```

...and you can error out if people don't do so very easy:

```
import os, sys
if not 'EASY_RSA' in os.environ:
    print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: Source vars before running this script"
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: I have done like you recommend early and did it now but still get same error(

Comment: `easy-rsa ...` was meant to be a placeholder for you to replace with your clean-all script or such. I thought this was obvious from the context.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation! seems combined command (prefix + cmd) works and at last I didn't get error but how to attach next command with user prompt to press enter? If I  simply add it to statement via "+" it doesn't work!

Comment: You'll need to show the exact command. If you were using the mechanisms I suggested in your prior question to avoid any prompting, this would be moot. :)

Comment: You can't use `+` to join them directly like that because there's no `&&` between cleanall and buildca. That's why I suggested an approach that would automatically add those separators in my comment on the question.

Comment: Also, why are you using the pipeline and ignoring the answer I gave you elsewhere (showing how to provide the newlines on stdin from your Python code), *and* ignoring the suggestion to use `-batch` to prevent openssl from prompting at all?

Comment: ...you could also use `prefix + cleanall` as one command, and `prefix + buildca` as another. (Need to make `cleanall` and `buildca` strings, not arrays, but that's a separate discussion).

Comment: I get all variables from user and insert them in vars, thats why I guess no need to edit openssl(btw, whitch of them,I have 3 ).I try to follow your recommendations but not sure I clear understand what to do (.

Comment: I run prefix + cleanall and prefix + buildca as two separate commands and it works!Thanks again!