# Python subprocess.call raise OSError with linux source command

Tags: python, subprocess

In python2.7 we can execute external linux commands using subprocess package.

```
import subprocess   
subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"]) // or  
subprocess.call("ls -l".split())
```

both works. I have a file test.sh in current work directory which contains just

```
date
```

so I tried

```
>>> subprocess.call("pwd".split())
/home/ckim
0
>>> subprocess.call("cat test.sh".split())
date
0
>>> subprocess.call("source test.sh".split())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 523, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What's wrong?
**ADD(ANSWER)** : This question and answer has enough information (but I'll leave my question here..) [Calling the "source" command from subprocess.Popen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040592/calling-the-source-command-from-subprocess-popen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`source` is a shell builtin command](https://superuser.com/a/46146/181209). Python's [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) is provided to spawn new process, not running a proper Bourne shell (or zsh or ksh or etc.). You cannot access shel builtins from `subprocess.call`.

To determine if you can or not run a specific command with `subprocess` module, you may want to use `which` to get information about the command you need to use:

```
user@machine: ~
$ which source                                                                                                                                  [7:41:38]
source: shell built-in command

user@machine: ~
$ which cat                                                                                                                                     [7:41:42]
/bin/cat

user@machine: ~
$ which ls                                                                                                                                      [7:41:47]
ls: aliased to ls --color=tty
```

Comment: Oh, that was the case. thank you! (so I should use execfile() function)