# A configuration file that can be read by python and shell

Tags: python, bash, shell, configuration, debian

I have python scripts and shell scripts in the same folder which both need configuration. I currently have a config.py for my python scripts but I was wondering if it is possible to have a single configuration file which can be easily read by both python scripts and also shell scripts.

Can anyone give an example of the format of a configuration file best suited to being read by both python and shell.

Comment: I've used `YAML`, and recommend it. There is also `python-yaml`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the simplest solution will be :

```
key1="value1"
key2="value2"
key3="value3"
```

in [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) you just have to source this env file and in Python, it's easy to parse.

Spaces are not allowed around `=`

For Python, see this post : [Emulating Bash 'source' in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503719/emulating-bash-source-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

**configobj**, a third party library you can install with `pip` can help with this.

```
from configobj import ConfigObj
cfg = ConfigObj('/home/.aws/config')
access_key_id = cfg['aws_access_key_id']
secret_access_key = cfg['aws_secret_access_key']
```

Configobj's homepage: https://github.com/DiffSK/configobj

Comment: I think you should add [<profile name>] before ['aws_access_key_id']. something like cfg[<profile name>]['aws_access_key_id']

Answer (score 1):

This is valid in both shell and python:

```
NUMBER=42
STRING="Hello there"
```

what else do you need?

Comment: I think the OP wishes for a method that doesn't break conventions. (I.e. don't open the file as a text file or start a subprocess or call `eval`)

Comment: This is exactly what I've been doing.  What I "need" now is to build/nest configuration.  For example:
BASE_DIR="/home/base"
CONFIG_DIR="$BASE_DIR/config"
How can I do this such that it's compatible with bash and Python and doesn't duplicate the config?  That's what led me to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I've experimented with using file name as value name and file content as value.

```
─┰ .settings/
 ┠─ var1
 ┠─ var2
 ┠─ var3
 ┗─ var4
```

And in shell you can load settings:

```bash
var1=$(<.settings/var1)
var2=$(<.settings/var2)
```

And in Python

```py
var1 = open('.settings/var1','r').read().strip()
var1 = open('.settings/var2','r').read().strip()
```

And you can trivially load all files into a dict

```py
from glob import glob

settings = {name: open(name, 'r').read().strip() for name in glob('.settings/*')}
```

if you want numbers to not be strings, you can add a function for loading data

```py
def read_setting(name):
    val = open('.settings/'+name,'r').read().strip()
    try:
        return(float(val)
    except ValueError:
        return(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping "config.py" rather than "config.sh" leads to some pretty code.

*config.py*

```
CONFIG_VAR = "value"
CONFIG_VAR2 = "value2"
```

*script.py*:

```
import config

CONFIG_VAR = config.CONFIG_VAR
CONFIG_VAR2 = config.CONFIG_VAR2
```

*script.sh*:

```
CONFIG_VAR="$(python-c 'import config;print(config.CONFIG_VAR)')"
CONFIG_VAR2="$(python-c 'import config;print(config.CONFIG_VAR2)')"
```

Plus, this is a lot more legible than trying to "Emulate Bash 'source' in Python" like Gilles answer requires.