# Python Sourcing a CSH and passing setenv to a new subprocess

Tags: python, testing, subprocess, csh

I'm currently trying to write some component tests for my team using python and I ran into a test procedure that tells the tester to source a csh file.  This file has a bunch of setenv commands and aliases.  All of these environment variables are needed by the next executable in the chain.  I wanted to devise some way to extract all of the env vars and pass them to the next process in the chain.

I looked at the following question, which is is almost what I need:
[Emulating Bash 'source' in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503719/emulating-bash-source-in-python)

It pushes all exported bash environment variables into a dictionary, which I can then pass to the next process.  The problem is this seems to only work for `export` and not the csh `setenv` command.

If this isn't possible, is there a way to run the .csh file with a subprocess command such as `/bin/sh -c script.csh` and then run the process that needs those environment variables as a subprocess to that process (so that it could inherit it's environment variables?)

Essentially, I have a process and script that has a bunch of setenv variables and that process needs to run in an environment that contains all of those environment variables.

Thanks for any help,

Comment: The only reason it only works for `export` is that it explicitly writes out `export` commands. Why can't you just change it to write out `setenv` commands instead?

Comment: Also, `/bin/sh -c script.csh` is not going to work, because you're trying to run a `csh` script with the `sh` shell, and they're different languages. It's like doing `perl foo.py`. But `/bin/csh -c script.csh` will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [John Kugelman's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3503781/190597)?
That would be the simplest way.

However, if for some reason you need or want Python to be an intermediary between these scripts, then you could use the following to source the script and retrieve the environment variables. (Edit: thanks to abarnert and Keith Thompson for the correct `csh` command.)

If `script.csh` contains

```
setenv foo bar
```

then

```
import subprocess
import os
import json
PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
output = subprocess.check_output(
    '''source script.csh; python -c "import os, json; print(json.dumps(dict(os.environ)))"''',
    shell=True, executable='/bin/csh')
env = json.loads(output)
print(env['foo'])
```

yields

```
bar
```

Comment: I don't think `/bin/sh -c script.csh` is going to work that well. While some simple `csh` scripts will also work as `sh` scripts, anything that uses, say, `setenv` (as the OP's clearly does) will not.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to let `csh` source the setup script and then run the other script. For example:

setup.csh:

```
setenv foo bar
```

script.csh:

```
echo $foo
```

runner.py:

```
import subprocess
csh_command = 'source ./setup.csh && ./script.csh'
subprocess.check_call(['/bin/csh', '-c', csh_command])
```

---

If you just want to use the code from the linked question, all you have to do is change the regex. Just replace `export` with `setenv`, and the `=` with `\s+`.

Comment: I'll try this at work on monday.  This looks like it will work.

Answer (score 0):

So `script.csh` contains `setenv` commands that set certain environment variables.

`/bin/sh -c script.csh` will just *execute* the script; the environment variables will be lost as soon as the script finishes.  Even that assumes that `script.csh` is executable; if it's meant to be sourced, it needn't be, and probably shouldn't be.

For the environment variable settings to be visible, `script.csh` has to be sourced *by a csh process*.

Here's a rough outline:

```
/bin/csh -c 'source script.csh ; python -c ...'
```

The `python -c ...` process will be able to see the environment variables. The process that executes the above command will not.

A more complex solution would be something like this:

```
printenv > before.txt
/bin/csh -c 'source script.csh ; printenv' > after.txt
```

And then compare `before.txt` and `after.txt` to see what changed in the environment. (Or you can capture the output in some other way.) That has the advantage of letting the calling process see the modified environment, or at least obtain information about it.

Note that in some unusual cases, you may not be able to determine the environment from the output of `printenv`. For example, if the value of `$FOO` is `"10\nBAR=20"`, that will appear in the output of `printenv` as:

```
FOO=10
BAR=20
```

which looks like `$FOO` is `10` and `$BAR` is `20`. (It's actually not uncommon to have newlines in environment variable values; my `$TERMCAP` is currently set to a 21-line chunk of text.

You could avoid that by writing your own `printenv` replacement that prints an unambiguous representation of the environment.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to get the environment from a shell script (that calls other shell scripts).  You could do something like this to read the env into a dictionary and then use os.environ to change the env.

```
    import subprocess

    SAPENVCMD = "/bin/csh -c \'source ~/.cshrc && env\'"
    envdict = {}

    def runcommand(command):
        ps = subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out,err = ps.communicate()
        outlist = out.split('\n')
        if ps.returncode == 0:
           return outlist
        else:
           return None

    def elist2dict(dict,list):
        for entry in list:
            if entry is not None:
               pos = entry.find('=')
               key = entry[:pos]
               pos += 1
               value = entry[pos:]
               dict.setdefault(key,value)

    def env2dict(dict,ENVCMD):
        envlist = runcommand(ENVCMD)
        elist2dict(dict,envlist)


    env2dict(envdict,SAPENVCMD)

    v = envdict["SAPSYSTEMNAME"]
    print v
```