# calling bash configuration files in python script to setup environmental variables

Tags: python, bash, operating-system, subprocess

I have a text file contains all the paths belong to bunch of commands that can be called in the `bash` scrpits and it is called `progs.ini`. 
Usually when I want to call this configuration file in my bash script I use this command

```
. progs.ini
```

**progs.ini** contains stuff for instance like this:

```
BIN=/bin/linux_64/
P_ANALYSE=${BIN}/analyse
NPARA=1
```

now I want to use some part of my code in python and I was trying to use this command as following:

```
import subprocess as S
import os
CMD='. progs.ini'
S.call([CMD],shell=True)
```

It doesn't return any error message but it can not recognise the variables which are defined in `progs.ini`

```
>>os.system('echo ${BIN}')

0
```

Well it is not about setting some environmental variable which is similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503719/emulating-bash-source-in-python). I want to set some variables using the configuration file.

Comment: The shell processes run by `subprocess` and `os.system` are unrelated. They do not share any state.

Comment: @EtanReisner so then what is related to this problem?

Comment: No. I meant the are unrelated to each other. You have effectively just run `bash -c '. progs.ini'; bash -c 'echo $BIN'` and wondered why the variable didn't work. Those two commands don't share any state. They don't share variables, etc. They are entirely different processes.

Comment: @EtanReisner Is there any way that I can set these variables which are a huge pile of them in my python script without re-writting them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using Linux.  In that case I would be inclined to put a `cat /proc/$$/environ` at the end of your ini file.  That will print out all the key value pairs in a format that's easy to parse.  This should do:

```
s = os.popen(". whatever.ini && cat /proc/$$/environ").read()
env_vars = {x[:x.find("=")]:x[x.find("=")+1:] for x in s.split("\00")[:-1]}
```

Tested.  That didn't work but this did:

```
s = os.popen(". ./whatever.ini && set").read()
env_vars = {x[:x.find("=")]:x[x.find("=")+2:-1] for x in s.split("\n")[:-1]}
print env_vars['hello']
```