# Runnuing a python script within another script many times

Tags: python

I have a python script that includes some data:

-My_Directory/Data.py:

```
Parameter=10
```

I also have a `Main.py` script, in which the `Data.py` should be called many times:

My_Directory/Main.py

```
call the Data.py to access parameter 
Manipulating and changing  parameter
          Some Code Here
call the Data.py to access parameter 
Manipulating and changing  parameter
```

How should I write the `Main.py` script to do the task?

I am very new to python and it is hard for me to follow the other similar posts. Would someone please answer this question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulating Bash 'source' in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503719/emulating-bash-source-in-python)

Comment: Does Data change or is used by something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Load Data.py contents in to the namespace by *exec*

Main.py

```
while True:
    exec(open('Data.py').read())
    if Parameter > some_number: # depends on your needs
        Parameter -= 1 # depends on your needs
    with open('Data.py','w') as f: # write back to file
        f.write('Parameter = {}'.format(Parameter))
```

Answer (score 1):

### reading parameters from another file

you can use

```
import Data
```

or

```
from Data import *
```

to explicitly import all the variables and functions of the `Data.py`. (if the importing file is in the same dir)

or if you want to import only one varible or function for an example "Parameter", then use like this

```
from Data import Parameter
```

to use the variable after importing just use the variable name like bellow.

```
print Data.Parameter
```

I am assuming you are not going to store the variable back in the `Data.py` file. If you are not storing the variable data back to physical file, i would recommend using a global variable to store data from the referencing file and refer it within the `Main.py`.

to do that just use a variable within the main function to store it. to modify the variable within functions use "global" variable to specify that you are referring a global variable, it will take as a local variable.

```
global testVar=20
testVar=20
def abc():
    global testVar
    print testVar
```