# Environment variables with AWS SSM Run Command

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, aws-ssm

I am using AWS SSM Run Command with the AWS-RunShellScript document to run a script on an AWS Linux 1 instance. Part of the script includes using an environment variable. When I run the script myself, everything is fine. But when I run the script with SSM, it can't see the environment variable.
This variable needs to be passed to a Python script. I had originally been trying os.environ['VARIABLE'] to no effect.

I know that AWS SSM uses root privileges and so I have put a line exporting the variable in the root ~/.bashrc file, yet it still can not see the variable. The root user can see it when I run it myself.
Is it not possible for AWS SSM to use environment variables, or am I not exporting it correctly? If it is not possible, I'll try using AWS KMS instead to store my variable.

~/.bashrc

```
export VARIABLE="VALUE"
```

script.sh

```
"$VARIABLE"
```

Security is important, hence why I don't want to just store the variable in the script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SSM does not open an actual SSH session so passing environment variables won't work. It's essential a daemon running on the box that's taking your requests and processing them. It's a very basic product: it doesn't support any of the standard features that come with SSH such as SCP, port forwarding, tunneling, passing of env variables etc. An alternative way of passing a value you need to a script would be to store it in AWS [Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html), and have your script pull the variable from the store.
You'll need to update your instance role permissions to have access to `ssm:GetParameters` for the script you run to access the value stored.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. As I can't mess with the production instances, I'll look into whether I can usenthe Parameter Store or KMS.

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this problem:

```
set -o allexport; source /etc/environment; set +o allexport
```

`-o allexport` enables all variables in /etc/environment to be exported. `+o allexport` disables this feature.

For more information see the [Set builtin documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)

I have tested this solution by using the AWS CLI command `aws ssm send-command`:

```
"commands": [
    "set -o allexport; source /etc/environment; set +o allexport",
    "echo $TEST_VAR > /home/ec2-user/app.log"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am running bash script in my SSM command document, so I just source the profile/script to have env variables ready to be used by the subsequent commands.  For example,

```
"runCommand": [
      "#!/bin/bash",
      ". /tmp/setEnv.sh",
      "echo \"myVar: $myVar, myVar2: $myVar2\""
]
```

You can refer to [Can a shell script set environment variables of the calling shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496702/can-a-shell-script-set-environment-variables-of-the-calling-shell) for sourcing your env variables.  For python, you will have to parse your source profile/script, see [Emulating Bash 'source' in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503719/emulating-bash-source-in-python)