# How to call snowsql client from python

Tags: python, shell, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I'm calling snowsql client from shell script. I'm importing properties file by doing source. And invoking snowsql client. How can I do the same in Python? Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Shell script to call snowsql client:**

```
source /opt/data/airflow/config/cyrus_de/snowflake_config.txt


sudo /home/user/snowsql -c $connection --config=/home/user/.snowsql/config -w $warehouse  --variable database_name=$dbname --variable stage=$stagename  --variable env=$env  -o exit_on_error=true -o variable_substitution=True -q /data/snowsql/queries.sql
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I tried to execute the same command with os.system()

Comment: Would you really want to shell into SnowSQL, which is a Python app, from Python -- rather than using the Python connector for Snowflake? If you have all the prerequisites in Python you can install it using "pip install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python"

Comment: As Greg has already mentioned - you should really be using the python connector for Snowflake rather than using the SnowSQL client from within Python.

Comment: through python i cant even assign variables in sql, it keeps throwing multi statement error and cant find an easy way around. But cli does it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're switching to using Python purely for improved control flow and would still like to continue using shell features, a straight-forward translation would require writing a function that [acts as the source command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3505826/9056819) to import environment variables, then using them in a subprocess call that executes with a shell to [allow environment variable substitution](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

```py
import os, shlex, subprocess

def source_file_into_env():
  command = shlex.split("env -i bash -c 'source /opt/data/airflow/config/cyrus_de/snowflake_config.txt && env'")
  proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
  for line in proc.stdout:
    (key, _, value) = line.partition("=")
    os.environ[key] = value
  proc.communicate()

def run():
  source_file_into_env()

  subprocess.run("""sudo /home/user/snowsql \
      -c $connection \
      --config=/home/user/.snowsql/config \
      -w $warehouse \
      --variable database_name=$dbname \
      --variable stage=$stagename \
      --variable env=$env \
      -o exit_on_error=true \
      -o variable_substitution=True \
      -q /data/snowsql/queries.sql""", \
    shell=True, \
    env=os.environ)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  run()
```

If you are instead looking to go purely Python without any shell calls, then the more [native connector offered by Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector.html) can be used instead of `snowsql`. This would be a far more invasive change but the [connection examples](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#connecting-to-snowflake) will help you get started.