# How to initialize env variable in current process with bash script when importing python package

Tags: python, bash

I have a custom python package which wraps some C code in library files (.so/.a). This C code depends on some env variables and I cannot change the C code.

To initialize them, I have a bash script like so:

```bash
PACKAGE_PATH=/path/to/package
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$PACKAGE_PATH/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PACKAGE_PATH/lib
etc.
```

The package structure looks like this:

```
my_py_package
├── __init__.py
├── env.sh
├── lib
|   └── libC.so
└── other_file.py
```

I would like to be able to automatically **source** the `env.sh` script in current process when importing my package in a script or console:

```py
# Loads env.sh in current process 
import my_py_package
```

I tried to update my environment with `os.environ` in `__init__.py` but it updates env for child processes not current process

I also tried to emulate `source` following this [Emulating Bash 'source' in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503719/emulating-bash-source-in-python) but the `os.execve` makes me lose the current process

It is possible to achieve this ?

Comment: I don't see any Python code in your question, so I don't see how we can analyze errors in it. In particular, I don't see how the bash code is integrated with your Python code. Usually, you would run your bash script and from this script, run your Python program.

Comment: @user1934428 Currently my bash script is not interpreted by the python part. For this to work I need to source it first and then run my python script, but I would like to package my package for pip and allow users to directly import the package and use it without the pre-launch step from the bash script.

Comment: How about separating them: Instead of a bash script, you provide a kind of a "property file", which just has definitions like NAME=VALUE, and this file can be processed independently from bash and from Python. I just wonder: You need PYTHONPATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH for Python to start up correctly, right? If this is so, where is the point in defining these values after you already have started your Python program?

Comment: That's an odd way of defining environment variables - normally they are separated with colons... not slashes.

Comment: Are you using the `C` libraries via `subprocess()` or some other way?

Comment: @user1934428 My python part is a wrapper around C libraries made with SWIG. The C part need the env variables and the python part is importing the .so with importlib.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The slashes were a typo, I changed them.
The C part is not called by any subprocess, SWIG directly generates Python objects for me that I can call and use in my Python code

Comment: If you can see the python code, How are you sure that the code is not overriding the values?